# LaTex align and split

Tags: amsmath

I am trying to split an equation inside the align environment, but I get an error message each time I try to add the \begin{split} ... \end{split} lines in the code below:

```
\begin{align} % requires amsmath; align* for no eq. number
%\begin{split}
    A & = B & C & = D \\
    & = E & &  = F \\
    & = G & & = H \\[5mm]
    I & = J & K & = L \\
    & = M & &  = N \\
    & = O & & = P
%\end{split}
\end{align}
```

The code runs perfectly as I typed it above, but as soon as I uncomment the split lines LaTex give me an error:
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
I am Any idea of what is not correct in this piece of code?
Thanks
DK

Comment: In its current form it is not immediately clear *how* you want the equation split. Can you mock up an image (or ASCII art) of what the current output is and what you actually want it to look like?

Comment: Werner, I wanted to make 6 lines of equations with 2 equations on each line. For each equation the "=" signs were supposed to line up with the equation above. I can get the equation to split, just using "align" (without the "split"), but in that case I get an equation number for each line (i.e. 6 numbers, one for each line). In order to get just one number for the entire set of equations I tried to add the split environment, but adding it gave me the error message. Let me know if you need more info or a picture and I will provide one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways of obtaining what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    A & = B & \qquad C & = D \\
      & = E &          & = F \\
      & = G &          & = H \\[5mm]
    I & = J &        K & = L \\
      & = M &          & = N \\
      & = O &          & = P
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{r@{}>{\null}l@{\qquad}r@{}>{\null}l}
    A & = B &  C & = D \\
      & = E &    & = F \\
      & = G &    & = H \\[5mm]
    I & = J &  K & = L \\
      & = M &    & = N \\
      & = O &    & = P
  \end{array}  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The first sets an `equation` (resulting in a single equation number) containing an `aligned` environment. This allows for the regular style `align` delimiting.

The second sets an `array` inside the `equation` instead of an `aligned` environment, with similarly formatted output. Mild horizontal spacing difference stem form the different column separation lengths.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason you know of why my code was not working? I looked up the code in The LaTeX companion book and also found it on the web. I could not see a reason why my approach would not work.

Comment: @user3734742: The [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) gives some good examples of how to use `split`. `split` can only handle a single alignment character `&` per row.